# Debian 7 - Disk lag when copying files

Tags: debian, hard-drive, lag

I'm hosting multiple game servers on a machine with Debian 7 and after a game server is created, a new game folder is extracted with the game files on it, which involves copying around 2-4 GB, and while the files are being copied, every game server freezes for around 3 seconds or more.

Is there anyway to avoid this lag?

I'm using `cfq` as the default `I/O scheduler`, but maybe there is a way to slow down the copying speed so the machine doesn't lag?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the reason for the slowdown, you might be able to use ionice or nice (I/O usage or CPU usage, respectively) to lower the priority of the copy.  This will incidentally slow it down if there is other load that takes priority.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been busy. Thanks for the tip.